Phone change firebase Authentication Firebase
I need to change user phoneNumber in Authentication, which function should I use?
My code:
// Update the phone number of the user in authentication and database
export async function updateUserPhoneNumber(
  email,
  newPhone,
  password,
  clearInputs
) {
  try {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if (!user) {
      showErrorToast("No user is currently signed in.");
      return;
    }

    // Reauthenticate the user
    const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);

    await reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential);

    // Update the phone number
    await updatePhoneNumber(user, newPhone);

    // Update the phone number in the database
    const userRef = ref(db, `users/${user.uid}`);
    await update(userRef, { phoneNumber: newPhone });

    clearInputs();
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

I know that PhoneAuthProvider is depricated and docs tells me that I should use verifyPhoneNumber.
